# Implementing Parse.Op.Increment() error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

hello I'm very new to javascript. I have only been programming iOS for a year. I am stuck on trying to increment a number in cloud code. I know I need to use Parse.Op.Increment() and amount(). but I must be doing something wrong I have gotten an error since I uploaded this line.

It DID look like this.(and worked)

```
var sum = Record.get("totalPunches");
Sum += request.params.punches;
Record.save("totalPunches", sum);
```

The line I am putting on cloud code looks like this.

```
 Parse.Op.Increment("totalPunches", amount(request.params.punches));
```

any help on what I am doing wrong?

thank you